# destroy a tkinter window an proceed further

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I created a tkinter Toplevel window for my application and later in the program destroyed it but after destroying the window the program doesnt get executed further and get struck there itself doing nothing . Here is the code that I used :-

```
#login.py
from tkinter import *

class gui:
    def __init__(self):
        #does something

    def login(self):
        self.winLogin.destroy()

    def guilogin(self):
         self.winLogin = Toplevel()
         btn = Button(self.winLogin,command=self.login,text='asd')
         btn.pack()
        self.winLogin.mainloop()


 #main.py
 import login
 from tkinter import *

 main = Tk()
 a = login.gui()
 a.guilogin()
 if True:
     #some code and this part doesnot get executed
     main.mainloop()
 else:
     main.destroy()
```

I run main.py file and the code get struck and do nothing before the if part . I tottaly have no idea whats wrong . Pls. Help!

Comment: you forgot `btn.pack()` to show button in window.

Comment: BTW: you should have only one `mainloop()` in all code - `main.mainloop()` - `Toplevel` doesn't need another `mainloop()`

Comment: you have almost nothing in your code so what you expect it should do ? Put at least `print("Hello World!")` is some places to see which part is executed.

Comment: That part which doesnt get executed executes when i manually close the window and all the print statement is outputted to the console after i manually close the window

Comment: `Toplevel` is used to create second/third window and you have `Tk()` as first/main window and you can do everithing in this window.

Comment: because all GUI (Tkinter/PyQt/wxPython/etc.) has something like `mainloop()` which works till you close window. everything after `mainloop()` is executed after you close all windows.

Comment: You have `buttons` and other widgets to start other code, or `after(milliseconds , function_name)` to call some function with delay. All GUI works different then console program and you have to learn it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As furas said in the comments, you should not call `mainloop` on the toplevel, instead use `grab_set` to disable the main window and `wait_window` to wait for the toplevel to be closed:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Toplevel, Button

def login():
    top = Toplevel(root)
    Button(top, text="Quit", command=top.destroy).pack()
    top.grab_set() # deactivate the main GUI while top is opened
    root.wait_window(top) # wait for top to be closed before doing the rest
    print("logged in")

root = Tk()

Button(root, text="login", command=login).pack()

root.mainloop()
```